# Sql query to delete duplicate rows

Tags: sql, duplicates, rows

I have three tables.
Diagnose, Patient and PatientDiagnose
The tables look like this

Diagnose:
uuid,text,date

Patient:
uuid,name

PatientDiagnose:
patientuuid,diagnoseuuid

One patient can of course have multiple diagnoses and two patients can of course have the same diagnose but the two diagnoses are represented uniqly in Diagnose with different uuids. Therefore the two patients are represented in PatientDiagnose with their patient uuids and each one with those unique diagnose uuid.

Now I have found out that I would like to fix something in my DB. I would like to delete the diagnoses that are considered duplicates for a patient. Duplicates are: if they belong to the same patient and has the same text, within the same year (use of year function on date?) and leaving just one of those diagnoses intact.

I would like to remove those duplicates since I only want one diagnose pr patient of the same text, a year.

How can I do that in SQL?

Tommy

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using. Also, please provide sample data and expected results as *tabular* text, and show us how you attempted to solve the question yourself so far.

Comment: Hope none of them suffers from two diagnosis like broken arm and broken leg...also, delete all records that have the same uuid and the same text and the date is the same...translate this in to sql and you should be good to go.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Please produce a SQL Fiddle? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

You say that a diagnose shall refer to exactly one patient. Your database, however, doesn't guarantee this, so you should fix that issue first. That would leave you with only two tables:

- Patient: patientuuid, name
- Diagnose: diagnoseuuid, text, date, patientuuid

Once you've converted your tables thus, you can easily do the cleanup:

```
delete from diagnose
where exists
(
  select *
  from diagnose other
  where other.diagnoseuuid  <  diagnose.diagnoseuuid
    and other.text          =  diagnose.text
    and year(other.date)    =  year(diagnose.date)
    and other.patientuuid   =  diagnose.patientuuid
);
```

You haven't mentioned which DBMS you are using. It may not feature the `YEAR` function. In that case try `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)` or look up date functions in your manual.